# Searching for ASP.NET autohide docking panel

Tags: asp.net, animation, panel

In few words:  I need panel that works like Visual Studio panels (for example Solution Explorer) with 'Auto Hide' turned on.

More detailed question:
I'm searching for docking panel in ASP.NET that can be docked to any edge of its parent programatically - for example dock it to left border (I don't need to change it manually in browser). Then it is minimalized to title only and after mouse hover it is expanded without resizing its parent - it should be displayed over parent panel.

Do you know any component that works in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Telerik RadDock](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/dock.aspx) or [Zee Web Dock](http://www.zettacube.com/Products/ZeeWebDock.aspx).

You want to look at [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) and [this article](http://xtractpro.com/articles/Docking-Panel.aspx) in case you want to roll out your own implementation.